# Need to manually delete a project from App Explorer

Tags: aptana

I deleted the .project file off the filesystem permanently and need to remove the subsequent project from the Aptana App Explorer so that I can re-create it with the same name.  The option to "Delete Project" isn't there, so it is just sitting in there even though the local directory is empty.  I need this to be gone, what is the brute force method to get this thing out of there?

Comment: Ran into the same problem as you a mere fifteen hours after you did! Hope someone has a solution for this. I was able to un-delete my project folder and work with it, but I would like to know how to do this as well. It seems strange that something so seemingly simple would be so hard to do.

Answer (score 10):

You will need to open/switch to the Project Explorer view (or the Navigator view), locate your project (might be a closed one) and delete it from there.

To open the Project Explorer, you can click 'Window -> Show View' and select it.

Cheers

Comment: It's also a good idea to delete the directory from your filesystem.  Sometimes files remain.  For me these files reside in my MAMP folder (`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`)

Answer (score 5):

For those still struggling to find the answer to this issue, the following procedure worked for me:

Make sure that the Project Explorer tab is visible. If not, choose Window -> Show View -> Other... and then expand the General group and click on Project Explorer. Click OK.

Within the Project Explorer tab, collapse the Local Filesystem group and then right-click any empty area with that window and choose Refresh.

When prompted to remove the orphaned project, choose OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a dummy project folder and .project file. Here's the one for my current Rails project, but there shouldn't be any reason why deleting those lines would make it not work, right? (I hope?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>ici</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.aptana.ide.core.unifiedBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.radrails.rails.core.railsnature</nature>
        <nature>com.aptana.ruby.core.rubynature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Once you have the .project in the right folder, you can click the gear icon and click "Delete Project."

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have the projects A, B, C. You have deleted the B project but it is still apearing in the "App Explorer":

1. Accesss to this workspace directory:  *Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects*
2. Copy folder A (some existing folder working fine), and rename it to B (with the name of the project you want to delete).
3. Open *Aptana Studio* and access to B.
4. Clic to *Open Project* if the button appears. If not, right clic and select *Refresh*. It will list the content of A project or an empty folder
5. In *App Explorer* toolbar, clic "*Delete Project*". Be carefull! don't check "*delete project contents*" or you will delete A project...

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the project folder from your local system make sure that the launch configuration for that project is also deleted so that it doesn't refer to a non existing project.

This worked for me:

1. Locate the launch configuration by clicking on Run-> Run Configurations.
2. Locate the project by typing it's name in the search box on your left.
3. Click on your desired long configuration to delete.
4. Once you have selected the launch configuration to delete, click on the red cross just above the search box to delete.
5. Close the dialog box
6. Relaunch Aptana.